# ActivityResultCallback not called for Image Picker

Tags: android

I'm moving to a new method of receiving activity results, aka ActivityResultCallback. There is some old logic that I'm trying to move to a new api, but I can't receive activity result for some reason. Here some code:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> avatarFromLibResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        startCropImage(result.getData().getData());
                    }
                }
            });

Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
avatarFromLibResultLauncher.launch(pickIntent);
```

This all is executed inside fragment. The app opens the Image Gallery and allows me to pick but result is not returned back to the app - onActivityResult is not called

Comment: your code is perfect , try to write a log in `onActivityResult` and check it..

Comment: @NikunjParadva I've added logs, they are not shown. Now I understood that it seems to be device specific problem on Samsing Galaxy S10E,  works fine on Xiaomi

Answer (score 1):

Please just try to debug the code is onActivityResult called inside parent activity of fragment or not if call then you can write the code like

> Fragment fr =
> getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourframelayout)
> fr.onActivitResult(requestcode,result code,data)

inside onActivityResult method of activity

Also please check tha data intent is getting.. if getting then try to get the path by using the contentresolver.query(an Uri from intent, filepathcolumn=mediastore.images.media.DATA,null,null,null)

picturepath =  cursor.getString(columnindex of filepath like DATA)

Hope this way may help you

Comment: Actually, it does call activity's onActivityResult but then what's the point of ActivityResultLauncher?

Comment: @Danil.B please check you pickintent line here please try with this(fragment) or context and then use putextra or action what you need just try this way once may help you to get the result in this class